# Using Dynamic templates correctly in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Passing values dynamically through templates in meteor fails, whereas doing so statically succeeds. What am I doing wrong? The set-up is as follows

I have the following 2 templates set-up in Meteor

```
<template name="search">
{{#each cards}}
    {{>card}}   
{{/each}}


<template name="card">
<div class="card">  
    {{docName}}
</div>
</template>
```

Passing values to this like this works perfectly

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.search.helpers({
    cards: [
      {docName: "Dr. Maga" },
      {docName: "Dr. Macha" },
    ]
 });
}
```

However, passing the same values dyamically like this fails

```
Cards = new Mongo.Collection("cards");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.search.helpers({
    cards: function() {
      return Cards.find({});
    }
  });
}
```

There is data in the mongo collection "Cards". I insert it after the app starts by using

```
db.Cards.insert({ docName: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });
```

and verify it using the following command

```
db.Cards.find()
```

which returns

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558b0a1394990bf66c75775d"), "docName" : "Hello world!", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-24T19:50:42.996Z") }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you setup the whole Pub/Sub mechanism Meteor relies on for sending data from the server to the client ? https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish

Comment: I have the below js file setup in the Server folder     Meteor.publish("Cards", function () {
      return Cards.find({});
    });

Comment: Did you also subscribe to the 'Cards' publication?

Comment: I have  also subscribed to this using the below code in a js file in client folder
    Meteor.subscribe("cards");

I also tried variations of "cards"/"Cards". doesn't work

Comment: The name of the pub and sub need to match. So if you are publishing 'Cards' you should subscribe to 'Cards'. If it is still not working the next step should be to check the client side console to see if Cards.find().fetch() is showing anything. Also confirm the directory structure so that you are publishing from a server directory and subscribing from a client directory

Comment: I first changed all instances of C|card to lowercase card to prevent name mismatches. Then I added autopublish and insecure back.

Now, when I do cards.find().fetch from client consolde, I get []. When I do db.cards.find() from cmd, I get { "_id" : ObjectId("558b1e0f94990bf66c75775f"), "docName" : "Hello world!", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-24T21:15:59.363Z") }

Answer (score 0):

The error was that the Cards collection was defined on the client side only. (Under the Meteor.isClient() Code block).

This means that meteor was trying to read from the Server, couldn't find the item coz it wasn't defined in the server side, and failed.

Solution is to define it in the "both" folder so that both server and client can access the collection.

```
http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/filestructure
```

Of course, don't forget to publish and subscribe to the collection.